# Why web service and proxy client not connecting?

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I have an application where I try to combine `Spring MVC` and `Apache CFX`(soap) web services.  When I run just the app, everything seems fine, I see generated WSDL by this link(`http://localhost:8080/services/customer?wsdl`). But when I run tests, it throws `WebServiceException: Could not send Message`... `Connection refused`.

I've opened all ports for public, private and domain area through `Windows Firewall Defender`. Maybe I've missed something.
In a desperate attempt to investigate it, I've checked the link with this command (`wsimport -keep -verbose http://localhost:8080/services/customer?wsdl`). As a result, it gave this:

```
[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/services/customer?wsdl

Failed to read the WSDL document: http://localhost:8080/services/customer?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>.


[ERROR] Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):

 At least one WSDL with at least one service definition needs to be provided.

Now I do not know which way to dig.
```

WebServiceDispatcherServletInitializer

```
public class WebServiceDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebServiceConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new CXFServlet());
        dispatcher.addMapping("/services/*");
    }
}
```

WebServiceConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
    public SpringBus springBus() {
        return new SpringBus();
    }


    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), new CustomerWebServiceImpl() );
        endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/services/customer");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

ClientConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfig {

    @Bean(name = "client")
    public Object generateProxy() {
        return proxyFactoryBean().create();
    }

    @Bean
    public JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean() {
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxyFactory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        proxyFactory.setServiceClass(CustomerWebService.class);
        proxyFactory.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/services/customer");
        return proxyFactory;
    }
}
```

CustomerWebServiceImplTest

```
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        PersistenceConfig.class,
        RootConfig.class,
        WebServiceConfig.class,
        ClientConfig.class
})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class CustomerWebServiceImplTest {

    private ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ClientConfig.class);

    private CustomerWebService customerWsProxy = (CustomerWebService) context.getBean("client");

    @Test
    public void addCustomer() {
        CustomerDto customer = new CustomerDto();
        customer.setName("John");
        assertEquals("Hello " + customer.getName(), customerWsProxy.addCustomer(customer));
    }
}
```

Could you give a hint where the error might be?

**UPD: I checked this setup on PC where I and my applications have full access rights and it still throws the Exception.**

Comment: The 403 (Forbidden) error usually points to authentication problems. Is there some code related to authentication (possibly through spring-security) in your application?

Comment: Thank you for pointing a direction. There's no spring security. Just Spring MVC and Apache CXF. 
I've developed by this guide https://www.baeldung.com/apache-cxf-with-spring

Comment: I have a guess. Maybe it's something kind of @CrossOrigin in Spring MVC? Web Service rejects access from clients by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was quite simple - just need to add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`. Because this annotation is run spring beans, not `@WebAppConfiguration` with `@ContextConfiguration`.

This is how it will look like

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        RootConfig.class,
        WebServiceConfig.class,
        ClientConfig.class
})
public class CustomerWebServiceImplTest {
...
}
```